# Why is HDMI audio working differently for Sony and Samsung?

Tags: raspbian, audio, hdmi

I have a strange different behaviour in raspbian showing up between two TVs. A **Sony Bravia 32W670A** and a **Samsung LA32A650A1F**

The simplest demonstration for this problem is to build the `hello_audio.bin` in `/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_audio/`

I run `hello_audio.bin` over and over in one console with this command

```
$ while date; do ./hello_audio.bin 1; done
```

That part works the same - the annoying sound will come from whichever TV is plugged into the HDMI at the time.

The difference is when I open Python in another console

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 13 2013, 11:20:46) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pygame import mixer
>>> mixer.init()
>>> mixer.music.load("foo.mp3")
>>> mixer.music.play()
```

The Samsung continues to play the annoying sound from the first console in addition to "foo.mp3"

The Sony goes silent as soon as `mixer.init()` is executed, and remains silent until Python exits (ie. you don't get to hear "foo.mp3" either!)

I only have the two TVs to test on at this moment, but I hope to add the results for a Panasonic to the list in the next couple of days.

Is it possible that the TV is changing the output of the PI? Or is something just confuddling the Sony?

**Edit:**
I found another way to reproduce. Instead of using pygame, simply

```
$ mpg123 foo.mp3
```

Again - either `hello_audio.bin` or `mpg123` work fine on their own, but playing both at once gives silence from the Sony. The Samsung plays both sources simultaneously.

Comment: If you are using pulseaudio (raspbian does by default), you might want to stop the daemon and run it in the foreground (it takes multiple `-v`s, e.g. `-vvv` = super verbose) so you can watch what it has to say while this is happening.  Might be exactly the same for both, but I guess it might also be different.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how sound is being sent to the two TVs. It sounds a bit like for one you're getting audio from the Pi (the Samsung) so the Pi can do the mixing. On the other (the Sony) you're sending digital data so the Pi has no opportunity to check.

You can force the issue by setting some options in config.txt and rebooting so you can control how audio is sent. Look at the `hdmi_force_edid_audio` option.

This is pure speculation, but it does fit the facts as you describe them.